# como seleccionar una fila de un datatable y mostrar el valor en un input

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel, datatables

```
 <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">CONSULTAR PROYECTOS DE SAP</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                            <table id="tabla_proyectos_sap" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width:10%">
                            <thead> 
                                <tr>
                                    <th>PROYECTO</th>
                                    <th>ACCIONES</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($proyectosht as $proyectos)
                                @php
                                $valorcito=''; 

                                    $valorcito =$proyectos->nombre_proyecto
                             @endphp
                               <tr>
                                    <td>{{$proyectos->nombre_proyecto}}</td>
                                    <td>


                                            <button id="{{$proyectos->nombre_proyecto}}" class="miboton">Presiona</button>                                          

                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
   <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 text-left">Requerimiento</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
           <input type="text"  name="nombre_proyecto" class="form-control input-lg" value=""  />
          </div>
         </div>
         <br />
         <br />
         <br />



         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 text-left">Nombre Proyecto Seleccionado</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
             <input type="text" id="nombre"  name="nombres" class="form-control input-lg"  readonly/>
            </div>
           </div>
```

estoy trabajando con un datatable y lo que quiero es que cuando le de click a un boton de seleccionar se me refleje el nombre de proyecto en el input de solo lectura abajo muestro mi codigo html, quisiera saber como seria la mejor manera de realizarlo, ya sea con js o php, pero que se me refleje el dato de la fila seleccionada[image: Coloco el Codigo html]

como puedo reflejar los datos de la fila dentro del input.??

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que muestras en la imagen. Lee [Como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Listo ya modifique la preguntai amigo estoy usando laravel, y normalmente reflejo mis datos. lo que quiero es seleccionar ya sea por el boton o con algun evento el nombre de proyecto y reflejarlo en mi input para luego guardarlo, lo de guardar lo hare despues que logre reflejarlo

Comment: Mencionas datatable.. Te refieres a la librería https://datatables.net/? Si es así, puedes mostrarnos como la implementas?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabla_proyectos_sap').DataTable({
    "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false,
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
        "language": {
          "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json",
          
      } 
  });
});

simplemente agrego los estilos y lo demas, listo

Answer (score 0):

En blade corrige el cierre del `@foreach`, para que no agregue la etiqueta `</tbody>` en cada loop

```
<table id="tabla_proyectos_sap">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>PROYECTO</th>
            <th>ACCIONES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($proyectosht as $proyectos)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$proyectos->nombre_proyecto}}</td>
            <td>
                <button id="{{$proyectos->nombre_proyecto}}" class="miboton">Presiona</button>                                          
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y en el js puedes hacer algo así (los comentarios de como funciona están en el código):

```
    // agrega un listener del evento on('click') para capturar cuando se presiona un botón
    $('#tabla_proyectos_sap tbody').on( 'click', '.miboton', function () {
        // cuando eso suceda, captura el valor de la primer columna, y asígnalo al input donde quieres mostrarlo
        var val = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
        $('#nombre').val(val);
    } );
```

Te dejo un snippet funcional (sin el php obviamnte) para que lo pruebes dándole click al botón ejecutar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#tabla_proyectos_sap').DataTable({ 
        "scrollY": "200px", 
        "scrollCollapse": true, 
        "paging": false, 
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">', 
        "language": { 
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json", 
        } 
    }); 
    $('#tabla_proyectos_sap tbody').on( 'click', '.miboton', function () {
        var val = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
        $('#nombre').val(val);
    } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="tabla_proyectos_sap">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th>PROYECTO</th>
            <th>ACCIONES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Subnuke</td>
            <td>
                <button class="miboton">Presiona</button> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Powegard</td>
            <td>
                <button class="miboton">Presiona</button> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 text-left">Nombre Proyecto Seleccionado</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" id="nombre"  name="nombres" class="form-control input-lg"  readonly/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el enlace al ejemplo oficial para este tema en la documentación de datatables: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

Comment: GRACIAS ME SIRVIO MUCHO AMIGO